# Change href attributes stops functionality with Rails and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an index of brands that I am looping through, with a link for each one that calls a method to add it to the table and make the text bold, using jquery.

```
<%= link_to brand.name, { :controller => 'user_favorites', :action => 'create_brand', :brand_id => brand.id, :user_id => current_user.id }, :onclick => "$(this).css('font-weight','bold');", :remote => true %>
```

This works fine, however, additionally, when the link is clicked, I need it to change to the remove link href, which points to a different method, which deletes it from the table. At the moment, I am just trying to get the href to change to "http://www.google.com". I have used this code...

```
<%= link_to brand.name, { :controller => 'user_favorites', :action => 'create_brand', :brand_id => brand.id, :user_id => current_user.id }, :onclick => "$(this).css('font-weight','bold'); $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');", :remote => true %>
```

Unfortunately, when I add `$(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');` the href does change successfully, but the controller action is not called, and the brand is not added to my table. It seems that I can either execute the controller action OR change the href, but not both. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

UPDATE:

As requested, the rendered html for one of the links...

```
<a href="/user_favorites/create_brand?brand_id=1272&amp;user_id=2" data-remote="true" onclick="$(this).css('font-weight','bold'); $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');">BrandName</a>
```

Comment: jQuery, and JavaScript, works client-side. Not server-side. It would be of help to see the rendered HTML, as seen by the browser, and also the jQuery script. Please, help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks David, I have updated my question with the html. There is no jquery script, I am calling the method obtrusively.

Comment: You need to return the response as well. after this line "$(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');" write return true. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Deepak, did you mean this?.. **:onclick => "$(this).css('font-weight','bold'); $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/'); return true;"**... as this has the same result, whereby the href is changed, but the controller action is not called.

Answer (score 0):

2 Things

1. I would not change the ORIGINAL link, I would hide the link to do X and show the link to do Y, that would be much less obtrusive and a better action toggle.
2. I would not use "click" to do the thing you are doing, I would fire a custom event on click, register to that event and then do something else.
   http://jsfiddle.net/fr7xK/

I am pretty sure this way will solve your problem since you are doing it async, first the first event ('click') will fire and then trigger the other event, which you register on